# regex to add filename into html document

Tags: html, regex, bash, notepad++

I am looking for a way to edit thousands of .html files adding them og:url with the URL basically taken from the filename. Basically, for every .html I want:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.example.com/NAME-OF-THE-FILE.html" />
```

--

My idea is to Search for **< /head>** and replace it for the needed code:
I cant figure out how to find the filename. How can this be done?

--

In simple words:

I search and replace in all **.html** files.

**Where:**

```
</head>
```

**Replace with:**

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.example.com/{FILENAME}" />
</head>
```

How can I do this? I don't know how to get the **{FILENAME}**  (name of the file)

Edit: *Bash seems interesting, but I'm a noob to it and don't know how to get this. Any help is very welcome.*

Thanks, thanks, **thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you got access in bash you can run this little script:

```
for i in *.html;do
  sed -i "s/</head>/<metaproperty=\"og:url\"content=\"https://www.example.com/$i\"/</head>/g" "$i"
done
```

EDIT:Missed some backslashes.The right sed command is:

```
sed -i "s/<\/head>/<meta property=\"og:url\" content=\"https:\/\/www.example.com\/$i\" \/><\/head>/g" "$i"
```

Comment: Thanks @Alator but I'm getting an error: 

sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unknown option to `s'

Comment: Sorry typo.The sed command must be like this: sed -i "s/<\/head>/<meta property=\"og:url\" content=\"https:\/\/www.example.com\/$i\" \/><\/head>/g" "$i"

Comment: There, sorry I couldn't find it at first. Accepted!

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following commands on a single `.html` file and let me know if this helps you, if you see it is working fie for a single file you could use it then for all html files then. This is in powershell and it comes mostly built-in with windows.(Please try them only on 1 file first as I haven't tested them)

```
(Get-Content test.html) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "</head>", "<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.example.com/{FILENAME}" />\n</head>" } | Out-File test.html
```

OR

```
powershell -Command "(gc test.html) -replace '</head>', '<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.example.com/{FILENAME}" />\n></head>' | Out-File test.html"
```

Comment: This gets me close, but it displays {FILENAME} instead of the file name. What I want it the name of the file to be printed out there. (answer for first code, second one does not run) Thanks!